# Correlating types in Elastic Search

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nosql

I have the following Elastic Search index, `my-test-index`, with documents grouped in the following types:

**owner**

```
  {
    "_index": "my-test-index",
    "_type": "owner",
    "_id": "AV4GXRQmXr6DxJJbKJTy",
    "_source": {
      "owner": "Jane",
      "pet": "cat",
      "city": "NYC"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-test-index",
    "_type": "owner",
    "_id": "AV4GXRQmXr6DxJJbKJT0",
    "_source": {
      "owner": "Jason",
      "pet": "snake",
      "city": "Boston"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-test-index",
    "_type": "owner",
    "_id": "AV4GXRQmXr6DxJJbKJTz",
    "_source": {
      "owner": "Jack",
      "pet": "dog",
      "city": "NYC"
    }
  },
```

and **type:**

```
  {
    "_index": "my-test-index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "AV4GXXuyXr6DxJJbKJUU",
    "_source": {
      "pet": "snake",
      "type": "reptile"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-test-index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "AV4GXXuyXr6DxJJbKJUT",
    "_source": {
      "pet": "dog",
      "type": "mammal"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-test-index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "AV4GXXuyXr6DxJJbKJUS",
    "_source": {
      "pet": "cat",
      "type": "mammal"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-test-index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "AV4GXXuyXr6DxJJbKJUW",
    "_source": {
      "pet": "penguin",
      "type": "bird"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-test-index",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "AV4GXXuyXr6DxJJbKJUV",
    "_source": {
      "pet": "parrot",
      "type": "bird"
    }
  }
```

I'd like to find out which pet types each owner has. For example, Jane has a mammal because her cat is of type "mammal." How can I write a query in Elastic Search to retrieve this info? Or, if it's not possible to achieve this in a single query, how could i execute the following steps?

1. Retrieve a list of all pets in `my-test-index`
2. Search for each pet's type in `my-test-index/type`

Answer (score 0):

If you include the type in the owner document, this woudl be a simple terms aggregation with a query that filters on the owner. You could also think about parent/child, but if the solution would be to add a single field to your documents I would try to do that and keep it simple.